# AWS SageMaker: could not load debugger information of estimator

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am using a SageMaker notebook in AWS for training a ML model. When I created and trained the estimator successfully with the following script, I could load the debugging information (s3_output_path) as expected:

```
from sagemaker.debugger import Rule, DebuggerHookConfig, CollectionConfig, rule_configs
rules = [
    Rule.sagemaker(rule_configs.loss_not_decreasing()),
    Rule.sagemaker(rule_configs.vanishing_gradient()),
    Rule.sagemaker(rule_configs.overfit()),
    Rule.sagemaker(rule_configs.overtraining()),
    Rule.sagemaker(rule_configs.poor_weight_initialization())]

collection_configs=[CollectionConfig(name="CrossEntropyLoss_output_0", parameters={
    "include_regex": "CrossEntropyLoss_output_0", "train.save_interval": "100","eval.save_interval": "10"})]

debugger_config = DebuggerHookConfig(
    collection_configs=collection_configs)

estimator = PyTorch(
role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
instance_count=1,
instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
#instance_type="ml.g4dn.2xlarge",
entry_point="train.py",
framework_version="1.8",
py_version="py36",
hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
debugger_hook_config=debugger_config,
rules=rules,
)

estimator.fit({"training": inputs})

s3_output_path = estimator.latest_job_debugger_artifacts_path()
```

After the kernel died, I attached the estimator and tried to access the debugging information of the training.

```
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.attach('pytorch-training-2022-06-07-11-07-09-804')

s3_output_path = estimator.latest_job_debugger_artifacts_path()
rules_path = estimator.debugger_rules
```

The return values of these functions were None.
Could this be a problem with the attach-function? And how can I access training information of the debugger after the kernel was shut down?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is something wrong with the attach functionality. The approach that usually works to read details from training job is to use the Boto3 API to get the training job.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("sagemaker")

response = client.describe_training_job(
    TrainingJobName='string'
)
```

This should contain all the details related to the debugger. Please refer to the below link to understand what we get with the response object.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_training_job